# tf tutorial... running a broadcaster

Tags: ros, tf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in the tf tutorial.
in: writing a tf broadcaster (Python), while creating the launch file (in section, [running the broadcaster](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29#Running_the_broadcaster)), why it is written:

```
<node name="turtle1_tf_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
```

, because the node was created as:

```
rospy.init_node('turtle_tf_broadcaster')
```

not

```
rospy.init_node('turtle1_tf_broadcaster')
```

So how will ros identify the node??

Ans what does `respawn="false"` mean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278872/tf-tutorial...-running-a-broadcaster/) by [anwesha17k](https://answers.ros.org/users/32667/anwesha17k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-05**:
I reformatted your question to enable syntax highlighting (it's easier to read) and I included a link to the section of the tutorial that you're asking about (it's a good idea to link to anything you're asking about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though the node's source declared the name as `turtle_tf_broadcaster`, `roslaunch` allows you to rename a node using the `<node>` tag's `name` attribute. This way you can run multiple instances of the same node. If you tried to run multiple instances of a node with the same name you'd get a warning stating

```
[ WARN] [1486130761.721137111]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
```

The [`roslaunch` section of the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes) explains what the `respawn` attribute does

> `respawn="true"(optional)`
>
> Restart the node automatically if it quits.

So, if you're node dies for some reason it will automatically be restarted if you include the `respawn` attribute.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0